# Adding 1 to time column of strings in Google BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, string, time-series, google-bigquery

Column is a string for time of Year+FiscalWeek, such as "201916".

I've used REPLACE(COLUMN, "2019", "") to leave the column at week number, column now = "16"

But now I'm joining on this week with another table that is offset by one week.
I'd like to now add 1 to each entry down the column, such as 16=17, 18=19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way for that is to transform the fiscal week to `INT64` and then subtract 1 to the 2018 FW. This query should work for you:

```
SELECT * from table2019 a
join table2018 b on SUBSTR(a.week2019,5) = SUBSTR(CAST(CAST(b.week2018 as int64) - 1 
as STRING),5)
```

With some dummy data:

```
#standardSQL
with table2019 as (
 SELECT CAST(week as string) as week2019
 FROM UNNEST(generate_array(201901,201915)) as week
),
table2018 as (
 SELECT CAST(week as string) as week2018
 FROM UNNEST(generate_array(201801,201815)) as week
)
SELECT * from table2019 a
join table2018 b on SUBSTR(a.week2019,5) = SUBSTR(CAST(CAST(b.week2018 as int64) - 1 as STRING),5)
```

it returns:

```
Row week2019    week2018     
1   201901  201802   
2   201902  201803   
3   201903  201804   
4   201904  201805   
5   201905  201806   
6   201906  201807   
7   201907  201808   
8   201908  201809   
9   201909  201810   
10  201910  201811   
11  201911  201812   
12  201912  201813   
13  201913  201814   
14  201914  201815
```

It joins the week1 of 2019 with the week2 of 2018. Notice that the last week of 2019 may not match with any of 2018 if they have same number of weeks (or 2018 has less weeks than 2019).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning into a number.  If you are only dealing with one year, then:

```
select cast(column as int64)
```

You can then compare to the previous week.

For going between years, you have a problem.  Some years have 52 weeks and some have 53 weeks.  So, you don't know if the week before 201901 is 201853 or 201852.  Either a calendar table or the use of ISO definitions could hep here.

Comment: What function would you use once INT64 data type to add 1 down the column for the entire year?

Comment: @Harri . . . `cast(column as int64) - 1 = cast(othercolumn as int64`.  This only works within one year.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve for the column to enable a join

Comment: Thanks for your help though

Comment: @Harri . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  My previous comment has the `join` condition.

Comment: Column is called YR_FW with dates in string data type such as "201916" for each week.

Comment: In order to join with a subquery for the previous year, I've done REPLACE(COLUMN, "2019", "") and left with column of week numbers. Such as "16"

Comment: Now I need to inflate one year of this data to match the other year as FW1 of 2019=FW 2 of 2018.